# Why is Ubunutu 17.10 unable to set Win Key as Meta in Tweaks

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I'm trying to set the windows key as the meta modifier on Ubuntu 17.10, so that I can use OSX style keyboard layout on the IntelliJ editor.

When ever I go to the gnome-tweak-tool application, in the "Keyboard & Mouse" >  "Additional Layout Options" > "Alt/Win key behavior", and select "Meta is mapped to Win keys", I should expect that I can now create a shortcut using the Win key + a letter and IntelliJ would identify it as Meta + the letter.

But no matter the option I select in the "Alt/Win key behavior" menu, it detects the input as the Win key as "Super".

How can I map the Win Key to Meta?

It seems that I have the correct menu option, it's just not working as intended.

The output for the following commands:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources 
[('xkb', 'us+dvorak')]
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options 
['altwin:meta_win']
```

Edit:

After failing around for a while I have given up on 17.10 and reinstalled 17.04.

Works fine on 17.04

Comment: You may want to try to include the line `XKBOPTIONS=altwin:meta_win` in the `/etc/default/keyboard` file (and reboot).

Comment: Hey @GunnarHjalmarsson, thanks for the tip.

I now have this as my config: 

XKBLAYOUT=us

XKBMODEL=pc105

XKBVARIANT=dvorak

XKBOPTIONS=altwin:meta_win

BACKSPACE=guess

One thing I did notice, as I was playing around, was that this was only seeming to apply during login, and once my user was logged in, the changes would be removed.

I found this because I would remove the dvorak variant, and that would only apply while I was logging into my account after reboot, once I was logged in it would go from QWERTY back to dvorak again.

Comment: The settings in `/etc/default/keyboard` are system wide. They are not "removed" at login, by may be overridden by settings you made for the specific user (e.g. in Settings or Tweaks). Did it help for the Win -> Meta mapping?

Comment: No it didn't help yet. But I'll try and have a look through Settings or Tweaks to see if there is something that I have set at a user level that is overriding what I want.

Comment: Please show us what these two commands output: 1. `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources` 2. `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options` (But you'd better show us by editing your question, and not in a comment.)

Comment: Okay I added it to the question.

Comment: Same as in `/etc/default/keyboard`. Then I see no explanation why it would switch from `us+dvorak` and/or why the `altwin:meta_win` XKB option wouldn't work.

Comment: Yeah I didn't end up finding a solution either, because of this and some other issues, I've just decided to run 17.04 instead. No problems since I have made the switch.

Comment: Win key, meta key or super key are the same keys just using different names.